# Speech recognition based windows logon

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, windows-services, windows-7-x64

I have created a java application (runnable jar) for voice recognition.
Now, I want this jar/exe to run at/before windows log on, so that I could use my login credentials in a spoken way.
Please suggest what I need to do.
*My purpose is basically to get a speech recognition based windows logon system.*
I am currently using Windows 7 Home Basic.
**Note**: *Using my jar is not necessary but to anyhow get the functionality.*